# "Forbidden, you don't have an access" after adding "<VirtualHost *>" to the httpd.conf file

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, access-denied, phabricator

I configure a Phabricator on Oracle Linux VM. I have done everything as in official guide from Phabricator. Everything works fine - after typing ip adress to the browser I can see a apache main page. But when I add following lines at the end of the httpd.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *>
  # Change this to the domain which points to your host.
  ServerName phabricator.example.com

  # Change this to the path where you put 'phabricator' when you checked it
  # out from GitHub when following the Installation Guide.
  #
  # Make sure you include "/webroot" at the end!
  DocumentRoot /path/to/phabricator/webroot

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/rsrc/(.*)     -                       [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^/favicon.ico   -                       [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$          /index.php?__path__=$1  [B,L,QSA]
</VirtualHost>
```

I receive: "Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

What am I doing wrong?

**SOLVED**

I went to `/etc/httpd/conf.d/` and found 'welcome.conf' file. This line
`<Directory /usr/share/httpd/noindex>`
I changed to this:
`<Directory /<path>/phabricator/webroot>`
And alias is sth like this:
`Alias /.noindex.html /opt/phabricator/phabricator/webroot/index.html`

This works for me. I hope I can help

Answer (score 0):

[403 Forbidden](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/403-forbidden-or-no-permission-to-access) usually "means that your file has bad permissions"

Make sure that the path: `/path/to/phabricator/webroot`:

- Exists
- Has the appropriate permissions 755 or 644
- (Could be optional): Is owned by Apache (or whichever user you have for Apache)

Comment: I checked it and it wasn't this. I have already solved this problem adding some lines in another file. But now I forget where it was :) When I remined, I will update my question